# Got a wierd ROC curve and AUC of a classifier

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, classification

My training dataset has 9 rows(samples) and 705 columns(features+target) (Train_5, y_train_5)

My testing dataset has 17 rows and 705 columns  (I know the split is not right)(Test_5, y_test_5)

First I do this:

```
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier ()
fit = clf.fit(Train_5, y_train_5)
y_predicted2 = clf.predict(Test_5)
c_report = classification_report(y_test_5, y_predicted2)
print('\nClassification report:\n', c_report)



Classification report:
           precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.13      1.00      0.24         2
       1       1.00      0.13      0.24        15
```

This result is normal. But when I want to draw the ROC curve, it gives me the full thing and the AUC is 1!

```
y_predicted = clf.predict_proba(Test_5)[:, 1]
false_positive, true_positive, _ = roc_curve(y_test_5, y_predicted)
auc = roc_auc_score(y_test_5, y_predicted)
auc
1
```

And this is ROC curve.

[image]

This is clearly wrong! I mean how could a classifier with 9 samples for training gives you this?? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily wrong. We have to ask ourselves what the axes mean. They are the true positive and true negative rates. i.e. the fraction of items that are correctly and incorrectly labeled as the "positive class".

If 8 of your 9 samples are truly positive and the last one is truly negative. This is possible. Imagine taking a slider and classifying everything to the left as positive and everything to the right as negative. Think about what your true positive and true negative rates would be (for simplicity I'll use 5 total)

```
|+|+|+|+|-|
^
```

^Here, there's nothing to the left, so 0 things are classified correctly or incorrectly as positive. So both the axes are 0, let's move it over 1:

```
|+|+|+|+|-|
  ^
```

^Here, everything to the left is positive and classified correctly, we have nothing falsly positive. this will be the case for every point along the line

```
|+|+|+|+|-|
        ^
```

^ The same explanation holds true here. Let's move the slider one more time:

```
|+|+|+|+|-|
          ^
```

^At this point. Everything that is actually positive has been correctly labeled as positive and everything (i.e. the one thing) that's negative is falsly labeled as positive (thus False positive). This is why these curves always start and end at the diagonals.

I mean you also could have just messed something up...